# Upload "file" using Javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, onedrive

Here's the scenario:

I have this HTML page with a TextArea element on it.

When I click a upload button, I would like to upload the content of the textarea as a file.

I have found several examples that shows how to do this for an existing file on disc.

What I'm trying to do is edit text in the textarea and then upload the "file" to SkyDrive using the REST API provided by Microsoft.

Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: why would you do that? The textarea is sent as text in POST request! You can do whatever you want with it at the server (put it to file, db, ...)

Comment: This should be done on the server side, not on the client with JavaScript...

Comment: I'm trying to create a web based Markdown editor without the need for a server side application. The idea is to store the markdown documents on SkyDrive and be able to edit them in the web page.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the upload button's action with a custom handler which performs an AJAX [PUT request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/hh561740#uploading_files) with content taken from the textarea.  In jQuery it would be something like this (untested):

```javascript
$('#my-submit-button').on('click', function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: 'my/skydrive/url',
    processData: false,
    data: $('#my-textarea').val(),
    success: function() { /* Success handler */ },
    error: function() { /* Error handler */ }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it!!